# convert BGR to Lab without OpenCV

Tags: c++, rgb, color-space, bgr, lab-color-space

With little experience in color spaces, I used the following code to convert BGR image (array of unsigned characters where each channel ranges from 0 to 255) to lab color space:

```
double F(double input) // function f(...), which is used for defining L, a and b changes within [4/29,1]
{
    if (input > 0.008856)
        return (pow(input, 0.333333333)); // maximum 1
    else
        return ((841/108)*input + 4/29);  //841/108 = 29*29/36*16
}

// RGB to XYZ
void RGBtoXYZ(uchar R, uchar G, uchar B, double &X, double &Y, double &Z)
{
    // RGB Working Space: sRGB 
    // Reference White: D65
    X = 0.412453*R + 0.357580*G + 0.189423*B; // maximum value = 0.959456 * 255 = 244.66128
    Y = 0.212671*R + 0.715160*G + 0.072169*B; // maximum value = 1 * 255 = 255
    Z = 0.019334*R + 0.119193*G + 0.950227*B; //  maximum value = 1.088754 * 255 = 277.63227
}

// XYZ to CIELab
void XYZtoLab(double X, double Y, double Z, double &L, double &a, double &b)
{
    const double Xo = 244.66128; // reference white
    const double Yo = 255.0;
    const double Zo = 277.63227;
    L = 116 * F(Y / Yo) - 16; // maximum L = 100
    a = 500 * (F(X / Xo) - F(Y / Yo)); // maximum 
    b = 200 * (F(Y / Yo) - F(Z / Zo));
}

// RGB to CIELab
void RGBtoLab(double R, double G, double B, double &L, double &a, double &b)
{
    double X, Y, Z;
    RGBtoXYZ(R, G, B, X, Y, Z);
    XYZtoLab(X, Y, Z, L, a, b);
}
```

I have re-converted the resulting lab image to BGR (using cvtcolor) to display it using OpenCV using the following code (I don't want to do the conversion using OpenCV, I have just used it to display the results. Basically I wanted to understand how color space conversion works):

```
// Lchannel, Achannel, Bchannel are arrays of type double
cv::Mat temp64bitL(height, width, CV_64FC1, Lchannel);
cv::Mat temp32bitL;
temp64bitL.convertTo(temp32bitL, CV_32F);

cv::Mat temp64bitA(height, width, CV_64FC1, Achannel);
cv::Mat temp32bitA;
temp64bitA.convertTo(temp32bitA, CV_32F);
cv::Mat temp64bitB(height, width, CV_64FC1, Bchannel);
cv::Mat temp32bitB;
temp64bitB.convertTo(temp32bitB, CV_32F);
    cv::Mat chan[3] = {
    temp32bitL, temp32bitA, temp32bitB
};
cv::Mat merged;
cv::merge(chan, 3, merged);
cv::Mat BGRImage;
cv::cvtColor(merged, BGRImage, CV_Lab2BGR, 3);
```

However, [the computed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQlPq.jpg) is different from [the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1IFm.jpg). is that due to a problem in the code?

Comment: on an image segmentation project I have worked, I have used different reference values. We have used D65 / CIE-1931 with `Xo = 95.047`, `Yo = 100.000` and `Zo = 108.883`. Could you try with those reference values and let me know if they work? Moreover, there is a function called `cbrt` if you `#include <cmath>`, that might be better to use for taking cubic roots.

Comment: What is the color space of the BGR input?

Comment: @JiveDadson Thanks alot for your comment. As far as I can tell it is sRGB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a bug in `double F(double input)`. It does not work as intended because of the integer division you have. You might be willing to change the function to read something like below. Note the `double` castings to make the divisions work in the floating-point domain, and the use of `cbrt` instead of `pow`.

```cpp
#include <cmath>

double F(double input) // function f(...), which is used for defining L, a and b
                       // changes within [4/29,1]
{
  if (input > 0.008856)
    return std::cbrt(input); // maximum 1 --- prefer cbrt to pow for cubic root
  else
    return ((double(841) / 108) * input +
            double(4) / 29); // 841/108 = 29*29/36*16
}
```

Then, another problem could be the reference values you are using for the XYZ space. We have the below reference values, coming from D65 / CIE-1931:

```cpp
double Xo = 95.047;
double Yo = 100;
double Zo = 108.883;
```

Then, our `RGBtoXYZ` conversion was working like this:

```cpp
template <class float_t> struct Convert<XYZ<float_t>> {
  template <class real_t> static XYZ<float_t> from(const RGB<real_t> &rhs) {
    // Assume RGB has the type invariance satisfied, i.e., channels \in [0,255]
    float_t var_R = float_t(rhs.comp1()) / 255;
    float_t var_G = float_t(rhs.comp2()) / 255;
    float_t var_B = float_t(rhs.comp3()) / 255;

    var_R = (var_R > 0.04045) ? std::pow((var_R + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
                              : var_R / 12.92;
    var_G = (var_G > 0.04045) ? std::pow((var_G + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
                              : var_G / 12.92;
    var_B = (var_B > 0.04045) ? std::pow((var_B + 0.055) / 1.055, 2.4)
                              : var_B / 12.92;

    var_R *= 100;
    var_G *= 100;
    var_B *= 100;

    return XYZ<float_t>{var_R * float_t(0.4124) + var_G * float_t(0.3576) +
                            var_B * float_t(0.1805),
                        var_R * float_t(0.2126) + var_G * float_t(0.7152) +
                            var_B * float_t(0.0722),
                        var_R * float_t(0.0193) + var_G * float_t(0.1192) +
                            var_B * float_t(0.9505)};
  }
};
```

where `RGB` was assumed to have its channels inside the valid range, as stated in the comment. Then, the `XYZtoLAB` function we have is the same except for the `cbrt` and reference value changes.

**EDIT.** Above numbers are obtained from [EasyRGB's Math](http://www.easyrgb.com/en/math.php) page. You can find the conversion from sRGB to XYZ and XYZ to Lab on the page, with a table of XYZ reference values. What we used was the set for "Daylight, sRGB, Adobe RGB."

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. @Arda I used 'cbrt' and double casting. Actually, the problem is in both the reference point and the values of BGR channels. I have a value ranging from 0 to 255 for each channel that is directly converted to XYZ through matrix multiplication. Solely changing the reference point results in a very bright image. However, when I add the operations that you apply to the RGB values before performing matrix multiplication the resulting image becomes similar to the original one. Could you please tell me more about these operations?

Comment: @HanaaIbrahim, I have edited my answer. Please have a look at the last paragraph. Basically, after fixing the integer division bug in your code, what you need is to decide on the set of reference values for XYZ. These are needed to convert properly from RGB to Lab. I do not know much about the details, but on the webpage I have listed, you can find a set of reference values for different lighting conditions together with the proper calculations. If you have found the answer useful and think it has solved your problem, please select it as the correct answer :)